# Embed font for visible signature

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add a visible signature to a PDF, and to achieve PDF/A conformance the font must be embedded. The following code:

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfToSign);
var os = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

var pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, os, char.MinValue);
pdfStamper.Writer.PDFXConformance = PdfWriter.PDFX32002;
pdfStamper.Writer.CreateXmpMetadata();
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;

var sap = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
sap.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 748, 144, 780), 1, "Signature");
```

throws this exception:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfXConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica
```

This makes perfect sense, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to actually embed the font. There's not much help in the iText documentation I found, but after searching around a bit I ended up trying this:

```
var font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, FontFactory.DefaultEncoding, embedded: true);
sap.Layer2Font = font;
```

And also this:

```
var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
sap.Layer2Font = new Font(baseFont);
```

Still no luck.

How do I embed the font in a visible signature?

Comment: Helvetica is one of the standard 14 fonts which every PDF viewer must know by itself. Thus, iText only contains some font metrics, in particular character widths, but not complete font programs for that. Thus, it cannot embed Helvetica. So you have to take a font program you have available and use and embed it.

Comment: Also, I believe that the font needs to be embedded for form filling (signatures are form fields) which will be different from embedding the font for content display.

Comment: Did not know about the standard fonts, but that was indeed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mkl mentioned, iText will not embed fonts that are *Standard Type 1 fonts*. Providing the font as .ttf-file instead worked:

```
var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"D:\Fonts\Helvetica-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```